# USB problem - device descriptor read/64, error -110

Tags: boot, usb, power-management

So, after setting up Ubuntu,

I still have the problem that start-up takes a long time (purple screen). I ran `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. Nothing too long here, I disabled some networking service previously.
Still takes a long time. So I use `dmesg` and scroll all the way up and this pops up:

```
device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

Here is also a picture of the dmesg output:
[:-(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqwwP.png)

Which takes a very long time. Apparentely there is a power supply problem according to some threads. I have a lot of micrcontrollers and arduinos connected (partly to a 4 USB HUB by Anker). This was never an issue on windows and all connected usb devices work without problem. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

UPDATE: I unplugged everything, waited 3 minutes and then rebooted (with partically connected USB devices like mouse/keyboard). It booted a lot faster. I hope it stays like that..

Cheers

Comment: Make sure your Anker hub has its power supply plugged in and working. Otherwise, you've got a USB device causing the problem.

Comment: Its just a USB hub, it does not have an extra power supply. To be fair, windows complained about some usb problem too, but it is not slowed down by it... Anyway I just unplugged the three arduinos which were connected, theyre power supplied externally now. maybe three of them draw too much power,

Comment: Yes, you need to get a powered USB hub.